# What are the values for the azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem template below?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, terraform-template-file

I have an `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem` template create by another team that i cannot get a hold of and i am trying to create the resources, but i am having a hard time creating a correct tfvars entry.

Template:

```
locals {
  access_map = {
    owner_other_access = {
      permissions_access = "---"
      type               = "other"
    },
    owner_group_access = {
      permissions_access = "r-x"
      type               = "group"
    },
    owner_mask_access = {
      permissions_access = "rwx"
      type               = "mask"
    },
    owner_user_access = {
      permissions_access = "rwx"
      type               = "user"
    }
  }

  default_map = {
    owner_other_default = {
      permissions_default = "---"
      type                = "other"
    },
    owner_group_default = {
      permissions_default = "rwx"
      type                = "group"
    },
    owner_mask_default = {
      permissions_default = "rwx"
      type                = "mask"
    },
    owner_user_default = {
      permissions_default = "rwx"
      type                = "user"
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this" {
  for_each = var.storage_containers

  name               = each.value.sc_name
  storage_account_id = each.value.storage_account_id

  properties = {}

  dynamic "ace" {
    for_each = merge(local.access_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_access))
    iterator = item

    content {
      type        = item.value.type
      scope       = "access"
      permissions = item.value.permissions_access
      id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "ace" {
    for_each = merge(local.default_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_default))
    iterator = item

    content {
      type        = item.value.type
      scope       = "default"
      permissions = item.value.permissions_default
      id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
    }
  }
}
```

with variable as:

```
variable "storage_containers" {
  description = "Storage Containers settings"
  type = map(object({
    storage_account_id = string
    sc_name            = string
    acl_access         = string
    acl_default        = string
  }))
}
```

My struggle here is:
`id = lookup(item.value, "id", null)`  - where is the template getting the user or the group name from?
and
`jsondecode(each.value.acl_access)` or `jsondecode(each.value.acl_default)` - what value does this have?
How will the tfvars variable look like in this case?

Thanks.

I am not sure if this template creates the containers and the ACL or just the ACL

Update: Is there a posibility to add a group or user asigned managed identity and allow it access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My struggle here is: `id = lookup(item.value, "id", null)` - where is the template getting the user or the group name from? and `jsondecode(each.value.acl_access)` or `jsondecode(each.value.acl_default)` - what value does this have? How  will the tfvars variable look like in this case?

The `ace` blocks in the template use the `jsondecode` function to convert the `JSON` string to a map, which is then merged with the `local.access_map` and `local.default_map` to create the access control entries.

Here is the updated `Terraform` code to create the `storage_containers` using the `terraform.tfvars` file.

Main.tf

```kotlin
provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    locals {
      access_map = {
        owner_other_access = {
          permissions_access = "---"
          type               = "other"
        },
        owner_group_access = {
          permissions_access = "r-x"
          type               = "group"
        },
        owner_mask_access = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "mask"
        },
        owner_user_access = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "user"
        }
      }
    
      default_map = {
        owner_other_default = {
          permissions_default = "---"
          type                = "other"
        },
        owner_group_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "group"
        },
        owner_mask_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "mask"
        },
        owner_user_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "user"
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this" {
      for_each = var.storage_containers
    
      name               = each.value.sc_name
      storage_account_id = each.value.storage_account_id
    
      properties = {}
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = merge(local.access_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_access))
        iterator = item
    
        content {
          type        = item.value.type
          scope       = "access"
          permissions = item.value.permissions_access
          id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
        }
      }
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = merge(local.default_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_default))
        iterator = item
    
        content {
          type        = item.value.type
          scope       = "default"
          permissions = item.value.permissions_default
          id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
        }
      }
    }
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```kotlin
terraform.tfvars

storage_containers = {
  container1 = {
    storage_account_id = ""
    sc_name            = "example-container1"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_user_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"<group_object_id>\"},\"owner_other_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_user_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"<group_object_id>\"},\"owner_other_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
  },
  container2 = {
    storage_account_id = ""
    sc_name            = "example-container2"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_user_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"<group_object_id>\"},\"owner_other_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_user_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"<group_object_id>\"},\"owner_other_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```kotlin
variable "storage_containers" {
  description = "Storage Containers settings"
  type        = map(object({
    storage_account_id = string
    sc_name            = string
    acl_access         = string
    acl_default        = string
  }))
}
```

After running the above Terraform code, the containers have been created.

**Output:**

```
terraform apply -var-file=terraform.tfvars
```

[image]

The specified group will have access to the storage containers.

[image]

Comment: Would this allow me to add different users, groups or service principals (either SPNs or user assigned managed identities)?
This is my goal at the end of the day, to add a group or an identity to allow it access from Databricks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your needs? Are you trying to assign users or groups to the Storage account?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works. It created access for the deployment service principal (he is now user and group owner). In a way, that's what i needed, but to extend access, i would like to add a specific group or user assigned managed identity to ACL to allow it access. In my case it would be a group and/or a UAMI. Is that possible with this code? If not, what needs to be changed?

Comment: Do you mean the above code, by default, is creating an SP with owner access? Instead of an SP, do you want to add a group or UAMI?

Comment: Yes, the code above created `Owner:SERVICE-PRINCIPAL-NAME(object_id)` with `rwe`, `Owner group:SERVICE-PRINCIPAL-NAME(object_id)` with `r-e`.

The SPN can remain there and i would like to additionally add a group or UAMI.
From the UI is pressing `Add principal` and you grant it some access based on wheter it's a user, group or Service Principal (in this case UAMI)

Comment: Hi @Alex, I have added an **Azure AD group** to the **ACL** as an update to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256486/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-alex).